# recalculation in google spreadsheets

Tags: function, caching, google-apps

so, functions in google spreadsheets recalculate in one of two ways: they either take new data and return a result with the new data, or they return a cached item from an earlier calculation. the path it takes is determined by whether or not parameter values are altered.

i'm wondering if anyone knows if there is an expiration on cached items?

so, will the function completely recalculate at some point when the cached return is deemed no longer current?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Turner